# Computer won't boot up

Tags: boot, motherboard, blank-screen

I am using asus P8H61-M LX motherboard.
My computer won't boot and the screen won't show anything.
The speaker produces high frequency sounds repeatedly.
I've tried to reset the CMOS, different power supply, disconnected everything unnecessary but nothing changed.
What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance,
amit farag

EDIT:
Ended up replacing the computer, the sound came from the microphone, replacing the cpu and ram didn't help so I had to guess it's the motherboard 
https://youtu.be/wSY69haen5Q

Comment: Do you get any beep sound from motherboard. Once the system is power on. Can you see bios screen in your monitor.

Comment: @techie gossip only the sound of the speaker. Can't see anything on the screen

Comment: Speaker is external one or from motherboard?.. better you clean the ram and insert try once. If ram have some fungus or moisture it. This happens.

Comment: @Techie Gossip Internal one. I've also tried to turn it on without a ram, just to see if it post or does anything different. I'm pretty sure that isn't the ram that causes it.

Comment: Did you check whether you can see keyboard num lock led is blinking on.. you can on and off the LED once it's power on. You told internal sound comes. How much beep count you get did you count that?? Tell me the beep count also

Comment: @TechieGossip I'll check with a keyboard soon. about the beeps - it's just a fast repeated beeps. i've counted more than 100 fast beeps but it is endless. i stopped counting, came back after few minutes and it still beeped

Comment: The beep will continue. once it complete the order. for example its beeps five and again five. it continue. You have recognize the set of beep.. I guess u can find that. The video you uploaded cant hear any beep sounds

Comment: It looks like a severe hardware problem. You can unassemble all parts and clean everything, make sure all connectors and jumpers sit tight. And try to remove all cards and disks to see if you can get into the BIOS. If not: junkyard. :)

Comment: @TechieGossip well, that's not a beep. the sound i am talking about is the one that sunds like mulfunctioned hard disk.

Comment: @eckes already tried to disconnect anything. will try cleaning it but i doubt it will have any effect

Comment: It's will due climate ram gets fungus and mositure.. so better clean it as below answer

Comment: Numlock won't respond (caps and scroll too). Cleaned the rqm and the slot. Will try to replace a cpu next week

Answer (score 1):

**Beep Code**

First You have to identify the Beep codes properly. If you Find any of these Beeps code please do the following steps. This are basic beep codes.

### 1 long 2 short Beeps (Memory/RAM)

- Clean the Golden Noch of memory using IP Solution or Pencil Eraser
- Clean the memory slots using brush.
- Reinsert One by One if you have two RAM. Check with single RAM First and respectively.

### 1 long 3 short Beeps (Graphics card) IF YOU HAVE

- Clean the Golden Noch of memory using IP Solution or Pencil Eraser
- Clean the graphics card slot using brush.
- Try to test the onboard graphics card if there is onboard VGA integrated

### 5 short Beeps (CPU)

- Check there are any damage's of CPU or CPU socket.
- Check whether the CPU fan is correctly connected.
- Check whether the ATX_12V power cable is connected well. Four PIN square from SMPS.